# Predicting own image with pretrained weights and biases doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist

I am trying to import my own images into neural network from scratch with backpropagation that has been trained on the MNIST database.

Code:

```py
#X - input image
#W1/W2 - Weights
#b1/b2 - biases

def predict(X, W1, W2, b1, b2):
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X.T) + b1
    A1 = tanh(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = softmax(Z2)
    prediction = np.argmax(A2, axis = 0)
    return prediction
```

```py
chosen_img = x_test[3]

output = predict(chosen_img, W1, W2, b1, b2)
myImg = chosen_img.reshape((28,28))
print(output)
```

**Where might be the mistake**

When I try to input an image from the MNIST database itself, it still doesn't work. For example, it can output this as an `output`: `[7 2 2 7 7 2 2 7 1 2 7 7 2 2 2 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 2 2 7 2 2 2]`.

Note that I am using the **same** code as in my full NN, so the Feedforward is the same, guessing is the same, and the weights and biases are the same - and it really works in that full version, so I really don't get, why it cannot work now.

Am I missing something? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You are building fully connected network, not CNN, your input should be 1D tensor of shape `28*28 = 784`, and your output tensor should be 1D of shape `10`.

According to problem description you are trying to build a neural net to classify `MNIST` digits. Right? Thus, your network should map input of shape `28x28` to the output vector of shape of `10` (predicted probabilities for each digit class: 0,1,...9), then you apply `argmax` to get predicted values.

Now, look at your `output` shape:

```py
# output array from the above issue:
output = np.array([7, 2, 2, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7, 1, 2, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2])
print(output.shape)
```

Output:

```py
(28,)
```

`28` vs `10`. And even more before applying `argmax` the output shape was `28x28`. So, it's definitely not what we want to achieve.

*The problem is in forward step.* You are building classic fully connected layers, but you are not reshaping your 2D input tensor of `28x28` to 1D tensor of shape `784`. If you want to work on 2D inputs you should use CNN architecture.

Thus, to fix your problem you should fix all the shapes of input as well as biases, weights.

Comment: Ah I see! So just to make sure if I understand you correctly:
My original network parameters shapes are:
Input - (10000, 784) 
Weight1 - (28, 784)
bias1 - (28, 1)
bias2 - (10, 1)
Weight2 - (10, 28)
Result after np.dot(weight, Input) + bias - (28, 10000)
Activation function - (28, 10000)

My predict function parameters shapes are:
Input - (1, 784)
Weight1 - (1, 784)
Weight2 - (1, 28) 
bias1 - (1, 1)
bias2 - (1, 1) 
Result after np.dot(weight, Input) + bias - (1, 1)
Activation function - (1, 1)

Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't understand that correctly. Now I think that I know what you mean, but it still output's wrong numbers.

So from original input size of `(10000, 784)` I have done `(1, 784)`

From Weight1 `(28, 784)` -> `(10, 784)`


From bias1 `(28, 1)` -> `(10, 1)`


From Weight2 `(10, 28)`-> `(10, 10)`


From bias2 `(10, 1)` -> `(10, 1)`



Now is this what you ment?

Comment: ok, you have dataset of n=10000 samples, each sample has m=784 features, number of hidden units, let's say will, be h=1024, output size o=10, input (n, m), thus (I am omitting activation for simplicity): input layer:  np.dot(W1 (h, m), input (n, m).T) + b1 (h, 1) -> A1 (h, n); hidden layer: np.dot(W2 (o, h), A1 (h, n)) + b2 (o, 1) -> A2 (o, n)

Comment: Just consider a neural network as a sequence of matrix multiplications and bias as adding with broadcasting, so:
`(1024, 784) x (784, n) -> (1024, n) + (1024, 1) -> (1024, n)`;
`(10, 1024) x (1024, n) ->  (10, n) + (10, 1) -> (10, n)`

Comment: Oh I see, thanks to you I was able to finally make it predict correctly!

Comment: It's glad to hear!)